# Http cookie not sent even though CORS is configured to allow access

Tags: javascript, cors

I have a web app that needs to access siteA and siteB (both are under my administration).  After the web app talks with siteA (and gets a cookie from siteA) and it jumps to siteB,  it needs to make a call with siteA, but the http request doesn't contain any cookie even though I configured (via cors) siteA to trust siteB and allow credential.

Have been googling and reading documents both in SO and other sites on this, however, I just can't get the cookie to be sent in the HTTP request. Here is the javascript that makes the API call with siteA (running in a page on siteB, browser is chrome)

```
await (await fetch("http://siteA/api/1/greeting", {credentials: 'same-origin'})).text()
"Greetings from Spring Boot!"
```

Here is the HTTP request sent by the above javascript.

```
GET /api/1/greeting HTTP/1.1
Host: siteA
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4117.2 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Origin: https://siteB
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

Here is the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://siteB
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Set-Cookie: jname=joe; HttpOnly
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 27
Date: Sun, 26 Apr 2020 17:58:48 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Connection: keep-alive
```

Any help or ideas are appreciated!

PS1: When I refresh a web page of siteA, I can see (from dev console) that the request has the cookie.

PS2: tried to use `credentials: 'include'` in the javascript snippet, it didn't work either.

Comment: Keep `credentials: 'include'` in the request as suggested but also try setting `secure` and `sameSite=none` in your response's `Set-Cookie` header

Comment: Thank you @Lennholm! You hit the nail on the head. To get it working, siteA needs to be on HTTPS, The cookie needs to have "SameSite=None;Secure" as you said and it should have "httpOnly" flag.  It now works.  I would like to give you and Nice-Guy each half of the credit, but I don't know how.

Comment: Your client is hosted on `https://siteB`, then why in your response it be set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://siteB` ?

Comment: Check the MDN docs, schema also affect same-origin policy https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try changing your code above to:

`await (await fetch("http://siteA/api/1/greeting", {credentials: 'include'})).text()`

See here: https://javascript.info/fetch-crossorigin

Comment: Tried it, `include` didn't any difference: the http request still doesn't have cookie.

Comment: maybe try `true` instead of include?

Comment: using `true` instead of `'include'` gave error saying the provided value 'true' is not a valid enum value of type RequestCredentials.

Comment: I marked it as accepted but it will only work if it's taken together with @Lennholm's great answer!